# Put unirest string response into a hashmap

Tags: java, unirest

I have a string response from a unirest request that I made and I was wondering if I could put the result into a HashMap for easier access of the response fields. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Here is a sample of the response:

```
{
    "access_token":"HzDzAtlom6CDqRa0zPetH09hZbDr8tm__hPw7aCx2m0h0gnGwHMaKvBEp64sHRUCJJEAlhCNUqQ3tBSyvod_93gTnt145W2ly9KKw5ISmaZRN75O9NUfJUGPRd0LH87LlxiRgHNFkUGTUDwyJOmhYNajj7TQoncxqkfc3jxL-jEi3Ea1cGRvOSmLH5Aqom81kKmiRzPV_Ss0xwFWjQVsS03y_P720Hv1BQEayO9L7Vic4A64GmXm3PlFQuwcvOk3M_7WOa_EEGOFBZdhwn7dzNQ7gypJ27MSTOD3gI57880unF4XFgTT_H4p4G5V6C8L8yRbRNXPIe80gLKYk3F3nw",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "expires_in":3599,
    "refresh_token":"f87a5fea7d764826be24bd742626d0d8",
    "as:client_id":"paymentApp",
    "username":"savemore01",
    ".issued":"Wed, 05 Dec 2018 03:13:23 GMT",
    ".expires":"Wed, 05 Dec 2018 04:13:23 GMT"
}
```

I tried to use split by using the comma(,) as a delimiter but the date and time fields got messed up. I hope someone could help.

Comment: The format of your input seems to be JSON, so you should use a JSON Parser to parse it (there are lots of libraries for that).

Comment: I would parse the content into an Pojo. This circumvents breaking with dates/times and eases the access.

Comment: you don't need to split. just get response as hashmap.

Comment: from a quick glance at the [unirest documentation](http://unirest.io/java.html) there appears to be a `.getBody()`-method that already does this for you: ".getBody() - Parsed response body where applicable, for example JSON responses are parsed to Objects / Associative Arrays." - have you tried that?

Comment: @Hulk yes the format seems to be in Json but the response is returned as `asString()`. I also tried the `getBody()` as stated in the documentation but my situation requires me to send one of the field values alone. I assume this will happen a lot more in the future, but will require different fields. So I thought I could parse them into a Pojo or hashMap

Comment: @flomo83 that was one of my ideas as well but I'm having trouble with the actual parsing as I am clueless on how to do that

Comment: @HadiJ I had a solution before wherein I changed the `asString()` into `asJson()` so I could pick the fields one by one. Apparently it caused errors so I'm kinda trying to avoid modifying the request sent to me by our client to avoid unnecessary debugging

Comment: @Uzi you can set any desired field into a POJO. Other fields which are not placed will be skipped. You will only get the placed fields if stated inside the POJO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectMapper is a very handy helper on converting between objects and strings.

**1) Parsing json string to hashmap:**

```
    @Test
public void it_should_test() throws IOException {
    //Given
    String str = "{\n" +
            "    \"access_token\":\"HzDzAtlom6CDqRa0zPetH09hZbDr8tm__hPw7aCx2m0h0gnGwHMaKvBEp64sHRUCJJEAlhCNUqQ3tBSyvod_93gTnt145W2ly9KKw5ISmaZRN75O9NUfJUGPRd0LH87LlxiRgHNFkUGTUDwyJOmhYNajj7TQoncxqkfc3jxL-jEi3Ea1cGRvOSmLH5Aqom81kKmiRzPV_Ss0xwFWjQVsS03y_P720Hv1BQEayO9L7Vic4A64GmXm3PlFQuwcvOk3M_7WOa_EEGOFBZdhwn7dzNQ7gypJ27MSTOD3gI57880unF4XFgTT_H4p4G5V6C8L8yRbRNXPIe80gLKYk3F3nw\",\n" +
            "    \"token_type\":\"bearer\",\n" +
            "    \"expires_in\":3599,\n" +
            "    \"refresh_token\":\"f87a5fea7d764826be24bd742626d0d8\",\n" +
            "    \"as:client_id\":\"paymentApp\",\n" +
            "    \"username\":\"savemore01\",\n" +
            "    \".issued\":\"Wed, 05 Dec 2018 03:13:23 GMT\",\n" +
            "    \".expires\":\"Wed, 05 Dec 2018 04:13:23 GMT\"\n" +
            "}";

    //When
    Map<String, Object> response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, HashMap.class);

    //Then
    assertThat(response.get("access_token")).isEqualTo("HzDzAtlom6CDqRa0zPetH09hZbDr8tm__hPw7aCx2m0h0gnGwHMaKvBEp64sHRUCJJEAlhCNUqQ3tBSyvod_93gTnt145W2ly9KKw5ISmaZRN75O9NUfJUGPRd0LH87LlxiRgHNFkUGTUDwyJOmhYNajj7TQoncxqkfc3jxL-jEi3Ea1cGRvOSmLH5Aqom81kKmiRzPV_Ss0xwFWjQVsS03y_P720Hv1BQEayO9L7Vic4A64GmXm3PlFQuwcvOk3M_7WOa_EEGOFBZdhwn7dzNQ7gypJ27MSTOD3gI57880unF4XFgTT_H4p4G5V6C8L8yRbRNXPIe80gLKYk3F3nw");
    assertThat(response.get("expires_in")).isEqualTo(3599);
    assertThat(response.get("token_type")).isEqualTo("bearer");
    assertThat(response.get("refresh_token")).isEqualTo("f87a5fea7d764826be24bd742626d0d8");
    assertThat(response.get("as:client_id")).isEqualTo("paymentApp");
    assertThat(response.get(".issued")).isEqualTo("Wed, 05 Dec 2018 03:13:23 GMT");
    assertThat(response.get(".expires")).isEqualTo("Wed, 05 Dec 2018 04:13:23 GMT");
}
```

**2) Parsing json string to object:**

*a) Resposne class:*

```
public class Response {

    @JsonProperty("access_token")
    private String accessToken;
    @JsonProperty("token_type")
    private String tokenType;
    @JsonProperty("expires_in")
    private Long expiresIn;
    @JsonProperty("refresh_token")
    private String refreshToken;
    @JsonProperty("as:client_id")
    private String clientId;
    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String username;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")
    @JsonProperty(".issued")
    private Date issued;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")
    @JsonProperty(".expires")
    private Date expires;

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public String getTokenType() {
        return tokenType;
    }

    public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public Long getExpiresIn() {
        return expiresIn;
    }

    public void setExpiresIn(Long expiresIn) {
        this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
    }

    public String getRefreshToken() {
        return refreshToken;
    }

    public void setRefreshToken(String refreshToken) {
        this.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Date getIssued() {
        return issued;
    }

    public void setIssued(Date issued) {
        this.issued = issued;
    }

    public Date getExpires() {
        return expires;
    }

    public void setExpires(Date expires) {
        this.expires = expires;
    }
}
```

*b) Parsing:*

```
    @Test
public void it_should_test_2() throws IOException, ParseException {
    //Given
    String str = "{\n" +
            "    \"access_token\":\"HzDzAtlom6CDqRa0zPetH09hZbDr8tm__hPw7aCx2m0h0gnGwHMaKvBEp64sHRUCJJEAlhCNUqQ3tBSyvod_93gTnt145W2ly9KKw5ISmaZRN75O9NUfJUGPRd0LH87LlxiRgHNFkUGTUDwyJOmhYNajj7TQoncxqkfc3jxL-jEi3Ea1cGRvOSmLH5Aqom81kKmiRzPV_Ss0xwFWjQVsS03y_P720Hv1BQEayO9L7Vic4A64GmXm3PlFQuwcvOk3M_7WOa_EEGOFBZdhwn7dzNQ7gypJ27MSTOD3gI57880unF4XFgTT_H4p4G5V6C8L8yRbRNXPIe80gLKYk3F3nw\",\n" +
            "    \"token_type\":\"bearer\",\n" +
            "    \"expires_in\":3599,\n" +
            "    \"refresh_token\":\"f87a5fea7d764826be24bd742626d0d8\",\n" +
            "    \"as:client_id\":\"paymentApp\",\n" +
            "    \"username\":\"savemore01\",\n" +
            "    \".issued\":\"Wed, 05 Dec 2018 03:13:23 GMT\",\n" +
            "    \".expires\":\"Wed, 05 Dec 2018 04:13:23 GMT\"\n" +
            "}";

    //When
    Response response = new ObjectMapper().readValue(str, Response.class);

    //Then
    assertThat(response.getAccessToken()).isEqualTo("HzDzAtlom6CDqRa0zPetH09hZbDr8tm__hPw7aCx2m0h0gnGwHMaKvBEp64sHRUCJJEAlhCNUqQ3tBSyvod_93gTnt145W2ly9KKw5ISmaZRN75O9NUfJUGPRd0LH87LlxiRgHNFkUGTUDwyJOmhYNajj7TQoncxqkfc3jxL-jEi3Ea1cGRvOSmLH5Aqom81kKmiRzPV_Ss0xwFWjQVsS03y_P720Hv1BQEayO9L7Vic4A64GmXm3PlFQuwcvOk3M_7WOa_EEGOFBZdhwn7dzNQ7gypJ27MSTOD3gI57880unF4XFgTT_H4p4G5V6C8L8yRbRNXPIe80gLKYk3F3nw");
    assertThat(response.getExpiresIn()).isEqualTo(3599L);
    assertThat(response.getTokenType()).isEqualTo("bearer");
    assertThat(response.getRefreshToken()).isEqualTo("f87a5fea7d764826be24bd742626d0d8");
    assertThat(response.getClientId()).isEqualTo("paymentApp");
    assertThat(response.getIssued()).isEqualTo(DateUtils.parseDate("Wed, 05 Dec 2018 03:13:23 GMT", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"));
    assertThat(response.getExpires()).isEqualTo(DateUtils.parseDate("Wed, 05 Dec 2018 04:13:23 GMT", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"));
}
```

Note that we easily applied date values with any desired pattern into the Date fields with the JsonFormat annotation.

Comment: I was already trying this approach but was having a hard time. Thanks for the JsonProperty. That one closed the deal

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the technology you use, Unirest offers parsing out of the box. 
The following example can be found here: http://unirest.io/java.html

```
// Response to Object
HttpResponse<Book> bookResponse = 
Unirest.get("http://httpbin.org/books/1").asObject(Book.class);
Book bookObject = bookResponse.getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of getting response body as Map in Unirest is:

```
HttpResponse<HashedMap> response = Unirest.post(Url)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body(requestBody)
                .asObject(HashedMap.class);
```

Now you have your response body as Map:

```
response.getBody().get();
response.getBody().put();
```